# KDB Converting Subselect to Q Query

Tags: kdb

We have a Q query running on tick data which consolidates to OHLC on 1-minute bars.

```
select subsel:(
         exec last datetime.date+1 xbar datetime.minute.z.Z
           from `base
           where instrument=`GBPUSD,
             datetime=datetime.date+1 xbar datetime.minute.z.Z), 
       max(datetime),
       min(datetime),
       Open:first price,
       High:max price,
       Low:min price,
       Close:last price,
       Volume:count(i)
  by DT:($)datetime.date+1 xbar datetime.minute.z.Z
  from `base
  where instrument=`GBPUSD,
    datetime>=2017.07.03T10:20:00.00,
    datetime<2017.07.03T10:20:59.999
```

The problem is the xbar date is synthetic on both the main table and the 'subselect', the exec "datetime=" needs to reference the main table and cannot find the alias approach to use. Considered an ej but as both sides are synthetic also could not find the construct.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your query before we even get to the subselect.  First, `datetime.minute.z.Z` is invalid syntax.  You probably don't need the `.z.Z` suffix there.  Second, `1 xbar` is redundant: `1 xbar x` is `x` for integer `x` and `datetime.minute` is integer. You can just do `datetime.date+datetime.minute` to get datetimes rounded to minutes.  (Note that if you use timestamps, as you should, rounding would simply be `0D00:01 xbar timestamp`, for datetime, you would have to precompute a minute as `U:reciprocal 24*60` and use that with `xbar` - `U xbar timestamp`.)  Fourth, you cast `xbar`'d timestamps to strings in the by clause. If you really want them as strings - do it as a separate update after the aggregation.  Finally, there are some minor issues such as redundant parentheses and `($)` which in q should be spelled as `string`.

Now, back to the subselect.  I think once you resolve the issues I highlighted above, you will find out that you don't need the subquery at all.  The result will already have the `xbar`'d timestamps in the key column.  If you want the result as a regular table - just use `0!`.